# shopping cart class JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

i want to make a shopping cart with JavaScript, i want make a Class that called 'Cart' that have a function like this

```
addProduct (productcode, quantity)
```

- this is a function to add product and will increment the quantity if we add the same product

```
deleteProduct (productcode)
```

- this is a function to delete the product

```
showcart()
```

- this is a function that will show the product and the quantity in the cart

so far i have done this

```
  class Cart{
    constructor(productcode, quantity){
        this.productcode = productcode;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        

    }
    addProduct (productcode, quantity){
        
        
        
    }
    deleteProduct (productcode){

    }
    showcart(){

    }
}
```

have no idea what to do next

Comment: No inspiration found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+cart+class) at all?

Comment: I think this is a vey wrong type of question, where you have done no research at all and want other people work for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I would go about it , you can test the snippet

```js
class CartItem{
    constructor(title,price, quantity){
        this.title = title;
         this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.updateQuantity.bind(this)
    }
    
    updateQuantity( quantity){ 
        this.quantity +=quantity
    }

}

 class Cart{
    constructor(){
        this.cartItems = [];
        this.addItem.bind(this)
        this.removeItem.bind(this)
        this.showcart.bind(this)
        this.checkIfItemExists.bind(this)
    }
    
    addItem(cartItem){
        //if item s already added to cart  increment its quantity 
        const alreadyInCart=mycart.checkIfItemExists(cartItem.title)
        if(alreadyInCart)
             return cartItem.updateQuantity(cartItem.quantity)
         //else just add the tem 
          this.cartItems.push(cartItem)
    }
    checkIfItemExists(title){
         return  this.cartItems.filter(item=> item.title == title)[0] != undefined 
    }
   removeItem (title){
        this.cartItems= [...this.cartItems].filter(item=>item.title !=title )
    }
    showcart(){
       console.log(this.cartItems)
    }
}

const item1 = new CartItem('item1',20,1)
const item2= new CartItem('item2',20,1)
const mycart = new Cart()

mycart.addItem(item1)
mycart.addItem(item1)
mycart.addItem(item2)

mycart.showcart()
```